# Why GWT is not supporting all java classes or methods?

Tags: gwt

From the below link I understood that GWT supporting only a subset of classes or methods in the following package in client side.

```
java.lang
java.lang.annotation
java.util
java.io
java.sql
```

https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/1.6/RefJreEmulation#Package_java_lang

Why is it so? 
I think it make more problem in development because I am using only GWT client and using REST Web service instead of server.

Is there any new release of jar like [gwtx](http://code.google.com/p/gwtx/) (new release for supporting persistence,annotation etc) for using all classes and methods in the above packages.
and my main doubt is why they are not supporting all?

Comment: Please, do not refer to a 4 year old documentation as a reference.

Comment: @Andrei Volgin Can you give anu new link?

Comment: @Thomas Broyer already gave it below: https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation#Package_java_lang

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To support translating Java to JavaScript, every *standard class* has to be **emulated**, i.e. recreated in such a way that the GWT compiler knows how to translate it to JavaScript. An `ArrayList` for instance is based around a JavaScript `Array`, `String` methods have to be emulated on top of a JavaScript `String`, etc.

And there are things that are simply impossible to emulate (files, sockets). A few other things are not emulated on-purpose, because the emulated version, while technically possible, would be much less performant than a more direct mapping of the browser APIs, and GWT strives for performance (third-party libraries, such as GWTx, can provide such emulations if needed) more than *compatibility* (the choice of Java as the language was primarily to leverage tooling, not provide a *compatibility layer* to allow reuse of existing libraries).

Finally, reflection is not supported as it would make it impossible for the compiler to prune dead code and do all its optimizations: how would it know that a particular class, field or method is not actually used by reflection rather than direct calls?

Comment: I want these methods Float.floatToIntBits(float) Double.doubleToLongBits(double)

Comment: Actually, [this project](http://gwtreflection.sourceforge.net/) provides reflection on the client side, should you want it...

Comment: [`Float.floatToIntBits`](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/super/com/google/gwt/emul/java/lang/Float.java#46) and [`Double.doubleToLongBits`](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/super/com/google/gwt/emul/java/lang/Double.java#108) **are** emulated. BTW, you were looking at a long-outdated doc (GWT 1.6 is 4 years old!) https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation#Package_java_lang (unfortunately, even that doc is outdated :-'( )